# Reflexive, symmetric, transitive sets?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am struggling to understand how to solve this task.

**Consider a relation R defined on the set of integers.** Determine for the following if the relations are reflexive, symmetric, transitive.

a. $R =\{(,)|=3\}$

b. $R =\{(,)|+\geq0\}$

c. $R=\{(,)|^2>\}$

d. $R =\{(,)|−3>\}$

In example a, am I supposed to consider a,b and 3 as part of the set?
If so, how is this solved with "-" and ">" etc?

Comment: a) is a relation (defined by the formula), b) is a new one, and so on.

Comment: Thus, you have to apply the [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation#Properties) to a), then to b) etc. and for each relation find the answer.

Comment: In my telephone I cannot see the most of your math expressions, because you did not use MathJax. Could you please add the default symbols and use `$...$` and `$$...$$`, please?

Comment: I really wish I understand what you mean by this. The problem is that I don't understand what to do with for example 3b (so far I have only worked with sets like R ={(a,b), (b,a)} and simple stuff like that.)

Comment: Start reading the formula defining $R$ : $R = \{ (,) \mid =3 \}$. $R$ is defined as the set of pairs $(a,b)$ of integers such that $a=3b$. Now, check in turns the definitions of : reflexive, symmetric, transitive.

Comment: What is 3b? There is no 3b here. Consider the second one for example. $(a,b) \in R$ means that $a+b \geq 0$. Now, does $(a,a) \in R$? Is $2a=a+a \geq 0$ for all integers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will solve part (a) only to give you an idea about how you can solve problems like this.

$$R=\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z} \mid a=3b \}$$

Is $R$ reflexive? To be reflexive, we must have that for any integer $a\in \mathbb{Z}$, $(a,a) \in R$. But $(a,a)\in R$ means that $a=3a$ which is false for all integers except $a=0$. So, the relation is not reflexive.

Is it symmetric? To be symmetric, we must have that $(a,b) \in R \implies (b,a) \in R$. Does $a=3b$ imply $b=3a$? Well, no. Because $a=3b$ and $b=3a$ result in the equation $a=9a$ which is again true for $a=0$ only. So, only the pair $(0,0)$ satisfies the condition for symmetry while if $R$ were symmetric, all pairs had to satisfy this condition. So, $R$ is not a symmetric relation.

Is it transitive? Well, transitivity means that $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$ should imply $(a,c) \in R$.

$a=3b$ and $b=3c$ imply $a=9c$ instead of $a=3c$. So, the relation is not transitive either.

Now try to check reflexivity, symmetry and transitivity for other relations given in the question.

Comment: I find this strange, that it isn't symmetric or reflexive or transitive. When I try to solve task b with the same logic I get the same answer as for this one - that it is not symmetric or reflexive or transitive. EDIT: I believe you are correct, but I am starting to wonder if my teacher might have written this task in a weird way

Comment: @TinaOlsen No, it's not strange. A relation doesn't necessarily have to be reflexive, symmetric or transitive. About part b, you're slightly wrong. The relation in part (b) is indeed symmetric because $a+b \geq 0$ is not any different from $b+a \geq 0$. Addition is symmetric. Isn't it? $a+b=b+a$. No? But you're right that b is not reflexive, nor transitive. It's not reflexive because $(-1,-1) \not\in R$ and it is not transitive because $(-1,1) \in R$ and $(1,-1) \in R$ but $(-1,-1) \not\in R$.

Comment: What if I say that
Let (-2, -1) ∈ R, (-1, -2) ∈ R

For (-2, -1) = a + b ≥ 0 and then

-2 -1 ≥ 0 which is 
- 3 ≥ 0

And the same for (-1, -2).
Is it symmetric because the "answer" is the same? (- 3 ≥ 0)

Comment: @TinaOlsen  But $(-2,-1) \not\in R$ because $(-2) + (-1) \geq 0$ is not true because $-3 \not\geq 0$. :P No. Being symmetric means that $(a,b) \in R$ should imply $(b,a) \in R$.  In this case, part b, $(a,b) \in R$ is the same as $a+b \geq 0$. And $(b,a) \in R$ is $b+a \geq 0$.  It is obvious that $a+b \geq 0$ if and only if $b+a \geq 0$. Right?

Comment: You are very correct sir :P I am sorry!

Comment: @TinaOlsen If you want to see another symmetric relation, here's one: $$R=\{(a,b) \in \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z} \mid \exists c \in \mathbb{Z}: a-b=2c\}$$ Now, this relation is symmetric because if $(a,b)$ is in $R$, then some integer $c$ exists that $a-b=2c$. Also, $(b,a)$ is in $R$ because $-c$, where $c$ is the same integer, works in the definition: $b-a=2(-c)$. Right? You can see that this relation is in fact reflexive, symmetric and transitive. :P Relations that are all the three are important in mathematics. They're called equivalence relations and you will study them later/soon.

Answer (score 2):

**How to read these:**

When describing a set like $R = \{(a, b)\mid a = 3b\}$, this is called *set builder notation*. It's a common way to write a set by describing all its elements instead of having to list them all.

Set builder notation works like this: $\{x \mid \varphi(x)\}$ denotes the set of all $x$ which fulfill the condition $\varphi(x)$. In the first example, you have $(a, b)$ as the first term here, and we're told that $R$ is a relation on the integers, so that means that $R$ consists of all integer pairs $(a, b)$ such that [something]. This something is written as $a = 3b$, and as $a$ and $b$ are integers, this is really read straight-forward an means exactly what it looks like it means.

So, the first relation is defined as "The set of all pairs of integers such that the first element is equal to three times the second element." So $(3, 1)$ and $(30, 10)$ and $(-6, -2)$ are in $R$, but $(1, 2)$ and $(5, -8)$ are not.